# How do I use a deserialized Type inside of a generic function? C#

Tags: c#, function, generics, types

I have a generic method (that I cannot change):

```
object SomeFunc<T>();
```

The trouble is that I save/load the Type of the object that I will be getting back. What I need to do is something like:

```
Type type = (Type)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(someStream);
Object myObj = SomeFunc<type>();
```

The above obviously does not work (I did not expect it to). However, I would like to know if it is possible to make this happen somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save a type, all you need to save is the [`Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). To call the generic method with that type you have to use reflection, as follows:

```
string typeName = LoadAssemblyQualifiedNameFromSomewhere();
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
MethodInfo method = this.GetType()
                        .GetMethod("SomeFunc", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .MakeGenericMethod(type);
object obj = method.Invoke(this, null);
```

(This sample assumes `SomeFunc<T>` is an instance method on the current object)